# How to run a service when the app starts in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I created a service SocketService, basically it initializes the socket to let the app listen on the port. This service also interacts with some components.

**// socket.service.ts**

```
export class SocketService {
    constructor() {
        // Initializes the socket
    }
    ...
}
```

I know the code in SocketService's constructor() only starts to run when a component use SocketService.

And usually the code in app.ts looks like this:

**// app.ts**

```
import {SocketService} from './socket.service';
...
class App {
    constructor () {}
}
bootstrap(App, [SocketService]);
```

However, I want this service run when the app starts. So I made a trick, just add `private _socketService: SocketService` in App's constructor(). Now the code looks like this:

**// app.ts (new)**

```
import {SocketService} from './socket.service';
...
class App {
    constructor (private _socketService: SocketService) {}
}
bootstrap(App, [SocketService]);
```

Now it works. The problem is sometimes the code in SocketService's constructor() runs, and sometimes not. So how should I do it correctly?

Comment: This guide has helped me: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html#don-t-use-new-with-the-heroservice-

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Stuart's answer points in the right direction, but it's not easy to find information on APP_INITIALIZER. The short version is you can use it to run initialization code before any of your other application code runs. I searched for a while and found explanations [here](https://gillespie59.github.io/2016/12/04/angular2-code-before-rendering.html) and [here](http://www.learn-angular.fr/how-to-call-an-asynchronous-service-before-bootstrap/), which I will summarize in case they disappear from the web.

APP_INITIALIZER is defined in angular/core. You include it in your app.module.ts like this.

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
```

APP_INITIALIZER is an [OpaqueToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289264/what-is-in-angular-2-opaque-token-and-whats-the-point) (or an InjectionToken since Angular 4) that references the ApplicationInitStatus service. ApplicationInitStatus is a [multi provider](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular2/2015/11/23/multi-providers-in-angular-2.html). It supports multiple dependencies and you can use it in your providers list multiple times. It is used like this.

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    DictionaryService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (ds: DictionaryService) => () => return ds.load(),
      deps: [DictionaryService],
      multi: true
    }]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This provider declaration tells the ApplicationInitStatus class to run the DictionaryService.load() method. load() returns a promise and ApplicationInitStatus blocks the app startup until the promise resolves. The load() function is defined like this.

```
load(): Promise<any> {
  return this.dataService.getDiscardReasons()
  .toPromise()
  .then(
    data => {
      this.dictionaries.set("DISCARD_REASONS",data);
    }
  )
}
```

Set up like that the dictionary gets loaded first and the other parts of the app can safely depend on it.

Edit: Be aware that this will increase the up-front load time for you app by however long the load() method takes.  If you want to avoid that you could use a [resolver](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data) on your route instead.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The current one only moves one line of code from a constructor to an `init` method. While constructors should indeed be kept as simple as possible, that thought alone does not make it a proper solution. Using `APP_INITIALIZER` does.

Comment: I don't think the selected answer is wrong, since it solves OP's problem. **BUT**, as I have a similar problem on some library's development, I've openned [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57361724/how-to-auto-run-a-service-from-a-module-when-its-imported-in-angular/57361725#57361725) where **this** answer would fit perfectly.

Comment: I think this solution is only works if the dataService is not using any Angular service. Because otherwise you get an "Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef" error.  [More Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441139/cannot-instantiate-cyclic-dependency-applicationref-error-in-ngmodule)

Answer (score 62):

Move the logic in your `SocketService` constructor to a method instead and then call that in your main component's constructor or `ngOnInit`

**SocketService**

```
export class SocketService{
    init(){
        // Startup logic here
    }
}
```

**App**

```
import {SocketService} from './socket.service';
...
class App {
    constructor (private _socketService: SocketService) {
        _socketService.init();
    }
}
bootstrap(App, [SocketService]);
```

Comment: i don't understand whats the logic behind do stuff in the method instead of constructor could you please explain this, whats the advantage of doing logic in the method ?

Comment: A cleaner approach imho

Comment: Constructors should be as simple as possible (normally only injection points), in case you need to add extra logic use the ngOnInit hook.

Comment: Yet another thing the team didnt thought of.. The more I work on Angular 4 I realise how brilliantly built is the Aurelia framework. It has all of these possiblities right out of the box by simply adding a decorator. Those guys know what they're doing.

Comment: What if the content of the initialization function is asynchronous? How do you force it to be synchronous?

Comment: @CodyBugstein It depends on your use case. If it's just fire-and-forget then just call the async method. If you need to wait for the result you can return a `Promise` from your `init()` method and then chain as needed. Whatever the case it **can** be done, but will probably be difficult and will be up to you to work out the details. If you need further help you can always post a question with details of your exact issue and the community would be happy to help you out.

Comment: @Sergio, [Angular does not yet support OnInit for services](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23235)

Answer (score 11):

Also see [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/APP_INITIALIZER-let.html), which is described as;

> A function that will be executed when an application is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

**socket.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SocketService {
  init() {
    console.log("socket service initialized");
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {SocketService} from './socket.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private _socketService: SocketService) {
    this._startupService.init();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Creating service constructor & then call it in ngOnInit() of your component.

- **Service Module**

```js
 export class SocketService {
    constructor() { }
        getData() {
            //your code Logic
        }
}
```

- **Component**

```js
export class AppComponent {
    public record;  
    constructor(private SocketService: DataService){ }
    ngOnInit() {        
        this.SocketService.getData()
        .subscribe((data:any[]) => {
            this.record = data;
        });   
  }  
}
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: @Hongbo wants the service to run when the app starts, not in one particular component that is using the service

Comment: This really simple answer worked for me.  I love simple answers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
in config.teml.json
{Domain:'your url'}

in app.module.ts

import * as mydata from '../assets/config.teml.json';
const data:any=(mydata as any).default;
let config: SocketIoConfig = { url: data.Domain, options: { } };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).