# Detect Back button pressed in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I'm trying to detect if the back button was pressed when I load this component. In the ngOnInit(), I'd like to know if Back was clicked so I don't clear all my filters. Here is the code:

```
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
constructor (private _productsService: ProductsService, params: RouteParams, private _categoriesService: CategoriesService, private _filtersService: FiltersService, private _router: Router, private _location: Location) {
    this.category = params.get('name') ? params.get('name') : null;
}

subscription: any;
category: any;
loading: boolean = false;
page: number = 1;
count: number;
products: any;
pages: Array = [];
errorMessage: string;

ngOnInit() {

    this.getProducts();

    //if(back button wasnt used) {
    //    this._filtersService.clear();
    //}

    this.subscription = this._filtersService.filterUpdate.subscribe(
        (filters) => {
            this.page = 1;
            var params = this.category ? {name: this.category} : {};
            this._router.navigate([this.currentRoute, params]);
            this.getProducts();
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: is the on keydown event not an option?

Comment: I need to detect if its a Back call

Answer (score 0):

In my application I created a `NavigationService` which contains a flag that can be used to determine if the back button has been pressed.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
import { tap, filter, pairwise, startWith, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NavigationService {
    wasBackButtonPressed = false;

    constructor(private _router: Router) {
        this._router.events.pipe(
            filter(ev => ev instanceof NavigationStart),
            map(ev => <NavigationStart>ev),
            startWith(null),
            pairwise(),
            tap(([ev1, ev2]) => {
                if (!ev1 || (ev2.url !== ev1.url)) {
                    this.wasBackButtonPressed = ev2.navigationTrigger === 'popstate';
                }
            })
        ).subscribe();
    }
}
```

It is using Rxjs `pairwise()` operator because I noticed that back button causes `NavigationStart` event to be sent 2 times, the first one has `navigationTrigger = 'popstate'` and that is what we're looking for.

Now I can inject this service into my component, and I can reference this flag to determine whether to run special logic if the user arrived there via the browser's back button.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationService } from 'src/services/navigation.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-example',
    templateUrl: './app-example.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app-example.component.scss']
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _navigationService: NavigationService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        if (this._navigationService.wasBackButtonPressed) {
            // special logic here when user navigated via back button
        }
    }
}
```

One other thing to know is, this `NavigationService` should run immediately at app startup, so it can begin working on the very first route change.  To do that, inject it into your root `app.component`.  [Full details in this SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35191617/how-to-run-a-service-when-the-app-starts-in-angular-2)

Answer (score -1):

create a variable in service , initialize it to false and set it to true inside the ngOnInit method.Since service gets initialized only once , add in ngOnInit :-

```
 ngOnInit(){
    if(!this._filterService.flag) this._filterService.clear()
  this._filterService.flag = true;
  //rest of your code
 }
```

Make sure service is initialized only once ,i.e when app is bootstrapped and not inside component's metadata.If page is refreshed , flag value will be false initially and true if component is accessed using back button

Comment: Thats not exactly what I need, I need to know when the back button was pressed so I dont call that service action. Otherwise call it