# Is that any other way to detect back button of the browser other than popstate?(Angular 6)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am using `Angular 6` and I want to know if there is anything other than `popstate` to detect back button of the browser?

If it's possible, then please elaborate. If it isn't possible, my problem is that I have two `sibiling components` both want to detect the back button event. When on back click,component travels to another also i included `window.history.forward()` which goes front to the component (i.e) route will not change and on back button previous component"s `popstate` executes and due to `window.history.forward()` current component"s `popstate` also executes.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: So what's wrong with popstate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Detect Browser Back Button event - Cross Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser)

Comment: I have two sibiling components both wants to detects back button event. When on back click the popstate in both the component runs this is the problem.

Comment: So detect it in the parent

Comment: Ok fine,On detection how can make it to run two different functions from two different components using the current active component?

Comment: What about implements in the on destroy ? Instead in the back

Comment: read my edited question!!

Comment: Please see the answer I have posted here: [Detect Back button pressed in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60099556/213050)