# Angular 8, how do I detect route is loaded normally or from a back button?

Tags: angular, angular8

I searched all over google but I cannot find a correct solution actually. My requirement is to find whether a page loaded from a back button or just by normal routing.

I found a solution to check whether it's from a back button or not

```
fromEvent(window, 'popstate')
      .subscribe((e) => {
        console.log('popped route');
        this.backButtonService.isBackClick = true;
      });
```

I need a solution to find whether it is loaded from a normal routine.... Help me, guys :)

Comment: Please see my solution in [Detect Back button pressed in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60099556/213050)

Comment: I will check it and update u @HDog