# Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1

Tags: angular

> I have added this code into my app.module.ts

```
    providers: [ AppConfigService,
            {
                provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
                useFactory: (config: AppConfigService) => () => config.getAppConfig(),
                deps: [AppConfigService],
                multi: true
            },
]
```

**Getting this error**

[image]

**Issue**: i have used [ngx-permission](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-permissions) pkg for permission. i set [route](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-permissions#usage-with-routes) permission method. but when i refresh a page that time redirect on home page instead stay on current page. so i tried [to load permissions before application start up method](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-permissions#to-load-permissions-before-application-start-up) for resolve this issue but got this error.

```
 config.getAppConfig() // call when application start up
```

have any idea please help. other solution also welcome.

Comment: How a service can be declared dependant on iself ? It seems to me that in "deps" you shall give Angular modules, not services. Can you just use a empty list as deps ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i had fixed my issue with this solution

create function into app.module.ts

```
export function loadConfig(appService: AppConfigService): Function {
    return () => appService.getAppConfig();
}

 AppConfigService,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: loadConfig,
            deps: [AppConfigService],
            multi: true
        },

issue into `HttpInterceptor` so i used injector for that
constructor(private inj: Injector) {
        super(
            inj.get(XHRBackend),
            inj.get(RequestOptions)
        );
}
```

Comment: Where you use the constructor? I

Answer (score 25):

This error can happen when the dependencies in your `APP_INITIALIZER` have a dependency on an Angular service, e.g. `Router`.

The solution is lazy injection by changing the constructor of your service to accept a `Injector` instead, and then resolve the value outside the constructor.

Example `AppConfigService`:

```js
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppConfigService {

  // Helper property to resolve the service dependency.
  private get _router() { return this._injector.get(Router); }

  constructor(
    //private _router: Router
    private _injector: Injector
  ) { }

  navigate() {
    this._router.navigate(['/']);
  }
}
```

Comment: your answer actualy inspired me not to use APP_INITIALIZER but create own APP_START token which is used in some app core module constructor to load all services after angular modules are ready

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue to dynamically update routes.
Actually, you don't have to inject dependencies manually. All you have to do is split the cycle. First resolve dependency, and then use them.
Here is an exemple for the router, but you can set any dependency you like.

```
// AppModule
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: myFactoryUpdatingRoutes, // init routes from special config
  multi: true,
  deps: [MyRouterLoader],
},
```

Config class:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyRouterLoader{
  // MyRouterLoader prevents cyclic dependencies.
  // Router cannot be part of "deps" of AppModule's APP_INITIALIZER
  // so we have to split dependencies resolving
  constructor(private router: Router,
              private routeConfig: MySpecialRoutesConfig) { }

  // actually update routes
  public injectSpecialRoutes() {
    this.router.resetConfig([
      {
        path: this.routeConfig.urls['my-home-url-key'],
        component: HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: this.routeConfig.urls['my-admin-url-key'],
        component: AdminComponent
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '/',
      }
    ])
  }
}

export function myFactoryUpdatingRoutes(myRouterLoader: MyRouterLoader) {
  myRouterLoader.injectSpecialRoutes();
}
```