# How to auto run a service from a module when it's imported in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I wonder how can I run a service from a module when it's imported without any manual service injection and run, just like the `RouterModule` does.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [

    BroserModule,
    MyModuleWithServicesThatShouldAutoRun,

  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **Disclaimer:** this is based on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44731279/4367683) in which was not accepted as the right answer because there was a simpler and easier way to do what the OP needed.

**You can use the `APP_INITIALIZER` injection token to run initialization code before any of your other application code runs.**

`APP_INITIALIZER` is defined in `@angular/core` and you include it like this:

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
```

`APP_INITIALIZER` is an [`OpaqueToken`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289264/what-is-in-angular-2-opaque-token-and-whats-the-point) that references the
[multi provider](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular2/2015/11/23/multi-providers-in-angular-2.html) [`ApplicationInitStatus`](https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationInitStatus) service. It supports multiple dependencies and you can use it in your providers list multiple times, e.g.:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    MyService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (service: MyService) => function() { return service.init(); },
      deps: [MyService],
      multi: true
    }]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This provider declaration is telling the `ApplicationInitStatus` class to run the `MyService.init()` method. `init()` returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and `ApplicationInitStatus` blocks the app startup until the `Promise` resolves.

```
export class MyService {

  // omitted other methods for brevity

  init(): Promise<any> {

    // start some observers, do the stuff you need

    // you can even request something via http
    return this.httpClient
      .get('https://someurl.com/example')
      .toPromise()
  }

}
```

In that way, anything inside init will run and block the application load until the `Promise` resolves.

Be aware that this can increase the up-front load time for you app by however long the `init()` method takes. For loading content before openning a route you should use a [resolver](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data) instead.

**Sources:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44731279/4367683 (answer in which this one was based)
- http://www.learn-angular.fr/how-to-call-an-asynchronous-service-before-bootstrap/

Comment: I'd like to call an asynchronous service that returns a subscription to an observable. So I need to save the subscription reference into a variable so as to unsubscribe when the whole thing goes down. And I would prefer to have this not delay the application startup as it can be run after startup time.

Answer (score 3):

What the `RouterModule` does is use a `forRoot()` and `forChild()` (sometimes called `forFeature()`) method, which is a convention to configure your module when it is loaded. A good description on how to implement that can be found [here](https://medium.com/slackernoon/when-to-use-angulars-forroot-method-400094a0ebb7).

If you take a look at the [`RouterModule`'s source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router_module.ts), you will see that `forRoot()` and `forChild()`configure the module like this:

```
providers: [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        provideRoutes(routes),
        {
          provide: ROUTER_FORROOT_GUARD,
          useFactory: provideForRootGuard,
          deps: [[Router, new Optional(), new SkipSelf()]]
        },
       // many more, omitted
]
```

In that place you could also add an `APP_INITIALIZER` as described in other answers, which would effectivly lead to your importing Module to look like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [

    BroserModule,
    MyModuleWithServicesThatShouldAutoRun.forRoot( /* some config, maybe */),

  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```